# How to clone all non-undefined properties with lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Given two objects:

```
let source = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
};
let overrides = {
    b: undefined,
    d: 4
};
```

How can I use the [lodash](https://lodash.com) module to produce a new object with the following deep-cloned values?

```
let result = _.cloneDeep(source, excludeKeysThatAreUndefinedInOverrides);
_.assign(result, overrides, excludeKeysThatAreUndefinedInOverrides);

console.log(result);
// {
//     a: 1,
//     c: { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 },
//     d: 4
// };
```

Where the key "b" is completely excluded (i.e. not assigned with the `undefined` value).

Comment: just do a merge then delete the undefined value's keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top answer works.

Here's a shorter version:

```
let result = _.extend(source, overrides);
result = _.omit(result, _.isUndefined);
```

I love chaining:

```
let result = _.chain(source)
  .extend(overrides)
  .omit(_.isUndefined)
  .value();
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for! I have posted an answer which demonstrates this with `.cloneDeep` but have accepted yours since it answers the question. Thanks!! The chaining syntax is great; I wasn't aware that this was even an option.

Comment: No problem. Chaining is great and most of the time leads to more readable syntax if you're familiar with lodash.

Comment: Note `_.omit()` only works in lodash v3 and earlier. If using lodash v4, use `_.omitBy()`.

Comment: Thanks @jamesjansson. This is an old answer. For those venturing in to use v4, please note that chaining isn't the recommend way to go about things. You can find reasons why on the internet. For myself, it's more about adhering to FP principles more than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`_.extend`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) to merge `source` and `overrides` and then remove `undefined` by using [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick):

```
let source = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
};
let overrides = {
    b: undefined,
    d: 4
};
let result = _.extend(source, overrides);
result = _.pick(result, function(element) {
    return typeof element != "undefined";
});
console.log(result);
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzkxL4dz/).

Answer (score 3):

This is a derivation of the answer provided by Quy which performs a deep clone and assigns the override values instead of a shallow copy with `_.extend`:

```
let result = _.chain(source)
    .cloneDeep()
    .extend(overrides)
    .omit(_.isUndefined)
    .value();
```